# Confused on how I would turn this Json response into a list

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have the model written correctly I believe..

For this json..

```
 [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  }
]
```

I have this model

```
    class Post {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String body;

  Post(
      {required this.userId,
      required this.id,
      required this.title,
      required this.body});

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
        userId: json["userId"],
        id: json["id"],
        title: json["title"],
        body: json["body"]);
  }
}
```

But of course the Json is a an array/list.. How would I extract the entire list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is written correct, and assuming your json is called `response` for example. You do this:

```
var response = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  }
];

List<Post> = reponse.map((e)=> Post.fromJson(e)).toList();
```

Because your JSON is a list of `Map<String,dynamic>`, you have to iterate\loop through the items in this json.

You can do that using the `.map` method for lists. It applies a certain logic, which you specify on every element in that last, and after your done, you gather all those operations, and add them to a list. So you can have a `List<Post>`.

Comment: So I just captured the response as  `final response = await http.get(url);

    final json = jsonDecode(response.body)`

Then I had to downcast the json as json as List<Post> but that is giving me the error 
`Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Post>' in type cast`

Comment: This will not work, because your response.body  is a list which contains `Maps`, not `Post` objects. Do as I answered and it'll work.

Comment: This will work if you insert it directly after `final json = jsonDecode...`

====> `List<Post> = json.map((e)=> Post.fromJson(e)).toList();`

Answer (score 1):

This is how i have tested your json

```
String data =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/new.json");

    final string = jsonDecode(data) as List;
    List<Post> posts = string.map((user) => Post.fromJson(user)).toList();

    print(posts.length);

    posts.forEach((element) {
      print(element.id);
    });
```

I made a demo of formatting JSON
you can check it [here](https://github.com/yeasin50/Dart_-Flutter_Advanced/blob/f42854646659c92684f012567fdbe48ebf3d1bda/lib/jsonFormating/sample1.dart#L33-L44)